# Suspicious PUT and GET requests in IIS logs

Tags: asp.net, security, iis

**The Situation**

I have come across some very suspicious PUT and GET requests in my IIS server logs. After Googling the requesters address, I have found information linking the IP's to known hacking teams. After each PUT there is an immediate GET for the same resource that was attempted to be uploaded to my server.

**Question 1:**
Would this be considered a remote code execution attack?

**Additional Testing Completed By Me:**

The IIS logs show that the response given for the PUT request was 412 'Invalid file type all files are not uploaded'

I have turned on Failed Request Tracing and attempted to upload text files using CURL and this is the same response I am provided with and was not able to upload a file.

**Question 2:**
What can I do to help prevent these type of attacks from being successful?

I can turn on IIS request filtering, but I am concerned that if I deny PUT my IIS application may be negatively impacted for any future web services.

Comment: It sounds like they are already unsuccessful.  You can't stop the attacks, even if you block their IP addresses, they'll just come from a different one.  And even if you try to figure out a way to block this kind of request, they'll just try others.  This is the reality of being connected to the web, constant attacks.  And that's why, even tiny throw away servers need to be hardened.. even if you think you're not big enough to be targeted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question 1: Would this be considered a remote code execution attack?

It is impossible to determine the intentions of the attacker from the information given. They could be looking to gain code execution, or they may simply settle for uploading their own content to your server for you to host, or to try and deface your site with their content.

> Question 2: What can I do to help prevent these type of attacks from being successful?

Server configuration and patching. The best advice I could give you is to reduce the attack surface - only enable the features you need. If you're not using PUT in your application, then disable it. Only reenable it if needed. Make sure you have the latest updates for your OS installed.

Security is a wide subject. You need everything from secure code when developing applications to rigorous security testing after.

Comment: Sufficient. Thank you.